# IIS 6.0 receives 404 error on files with a "." extension and nothing else

Tags: iis-6, mime, extension

I have an issue where I am reverse proxying from an IIS 6.0 server to an apache server which is serving PNG files with no extension. Strangly it serves files with a "." but nothing else, for example:

"http://internalserver/proxy/image."

I tried adding the MIME type "." and even ".*" to the IIS virtual directory and the server (via IIS MMC snap-in) but this hasn't seemed to solve the issue. Adding the mime type worked when testing other obscure extensions e.g. image.x, image.] etc, but if you have the filename and the "." and nothing else after it, it seems to fail with 404.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an entry called `*` with `application/octet-stream` as the MIME Type.

Comment: @AdamB I did try that, adding a "*" results in ".*" but still the same problem. I am wondering if its related to the fact that windows does not support filenames with only a "." extension and hence IIS follows suit.

Comment: Did you stop and start IIS?

Comment: Here are some instructions with pics: http://www.serverintellect.com/support/iis6/enable-no-extensions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the Win32 subsystem that all applications use, strips off the trailing `.` from all file paths - so IIS might try to be smart and do it itself.

Is the `.` present in the real file name? If yes, does it have to be? (Usually files without extension don't have the `.` either.)